# Doctrine query iterate not working on MS SQL Server - New transaction is not allowed

Tags: php, sql-server, pdo, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I'm trying to iterate over results and remove them using the entity manager, as described in https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.6/reference/batch-processing.html#iterating-results

However, I'm getting the following error when `flush()` is being called:

> PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\SQLSrv\SQLSrvException: SQLSTATE [42000, 3988]: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server][SQL Server]New transaction is not allowed because there are other threads running in the session. in D:\inetpub\wwwroot\vendor\doctrine\dbal\lib\Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\SQLSrv\SQLSrvException.php:54

```php
<?php

$batchSize = 20;
$i = 0;

$q = $em->createQuery('select u from MyProject\Model\User u WHERE credit < :minCredit');
$q->setParameter('minCredit', 20);

$iterableResult = $q->iterate();
while (($row = $iterableResult->next()) !== false) {
    $em->remove($row[0]);
    if (($i % $batchSize) === 0) {
        $em->flush();
        $em->clear();
    }
    ++$i;
}
$em->flush();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is because SQL Server can't begin a new transaction while iterating over a prepared statement.

The solution is to begin a transaction that includes the prepared statement and then committing after altering all objects.

```php
<?php

$conn = $em->getConnection();

$batchSize = 20;
$i = 0;

$q = $em->createQuery('select u from MyProject\Model\User u WHERE credit < :minCredit');
$q->setParameter('minCredit', 20);

$conn->beginTransaction();

try {
    $iterableResult = $q->iterate();
    while (($row = $iterableResult->next()) !== false) {
        $em->remove($row[0]);
        if (($i % $batchSize) === 0) {
            $em->flush();
            $em->clear();
        }
        ++$i;
    }
    $em->flush();

    $conn->commit();
} catch (\Exception $e) {
    $conn->rollBack();
    throw $e;
}
```